# Число "-858993460" при формировании массива из двух других массивов

Tags: массивы, c++

Добрый день,у меня вопрос: почему при формировании 3 массива из элементов 1 и 2,вместо 4 и 5 элемента из 1 массива встают не те числа,а именно "-858993460". И так при каждом запуске. Всё остальное работает нормально.

Фото прилагаю:

[image: Imgur]

Цель задачи:создать и отсортировать массив из 10 элементов,состоящий из двух других массивов по 5 элементов каждый.

Вот полный код задачи:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
void main() {
    int n1=5,n2=5,n3=10, i, j, temp;
    int a1[5],a2[5],a3[10];
     srand(time(NULL));
     setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

//массив a1
 cout<<endl<<"Массив1:";
        for(i = 0 ; i < n1; i++) 
           { 
            a1[i]=rand()%10+1;
            cout<<endl<<a1[i]<<" ";  //Вывод массива a1
           }

 cout<<" \n";

//массив a2
 cout<<"\n"<<"Массив2:";
         for(int i=0;i<n2;i++)
            {
             a2[i]=rand()%10+1;     
             cout<<endl<<a2[i]<<" ";   //Вывод массива a2
            }

 cout<<" \n";

//Формирование массива a3 из массивов a1 и a2
 cout<<"\n"<<"Массив3:  ";
         for(i = 0; i < n3; i++)
            {
             a3[i] = a1[i];
             a3[i] = a2[i];
             i+5;
             cout<<a3[i]<<" ";     //Вывод массива a3
            }

 cout<<" \n";

 //сортировка массива a3 методом вставок
 cout<<"\n"<<"Сортированый массив a3:  ";
  for (i = 1; i < n3; i++)
    {
         j = i;
         while (j > 0 && a3[j] < a3[j - 1])
            {
             temp = a3[j];
             a3[j] = a3[j - 1];
             a3[j - 1] = temp;
             j--;
            }
    }
    for(i = 0 ; i < n3; i++) 
    cout<<a3[i]<<"\t";    //Вывод массива a3
    cout<<"\n"<<endl;
}
```

Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: Интересное число. В шестнадцатеричной форме: 0xFFFFFFFFCCCCCCCC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//Формирование массива a3 из массивов a1 и a2
 cout<<"\n"<<"Массив3:  ";
         for(i = 0; i < n3; i++)
            {
             a3[i] = a1[i];
             a3[i] = a2[i];
             i+5;
             cout<<a3[i]<<" ";     //Вывод массива a3
            }
```

Здесь ошибка. Сливать нужно так:

```
         for(i = 0; i < n2; i++)
            {
             a3[i] = a1[i];
             a3[i+5] = a2[i];
             cout<<a3[i]<<" "<<a3[i+5]<<" ";     //Вывод массива a3
            }
```

Я сейчас попробую интерпретировать на русский язык твой способ
i изменяется от 0 до n3 ( 10  ) не включительно
Записать в a3 ( который имеет размерность 10 ) по индексу i число, которое записано в a1( размерностью 5! ) по индексу i. Уже здесь становится ясно, что когда i достигнет значения 5, у a1 будет выход за границы массива.
со второй строчкой тоже самое только, вместо а1, а2.
а в 3-ей просто к i+5 и всё. никуда результат не записать.

PS: И это не C, а C++ :)

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Так,всё получилось, я понял в чем проблема=)